# execute function after the previous one is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, onload

I'm trying to execute function after anotherfunction but I'm getting this error in chrome:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined

The functions look like this but I  guess it's not so important because they works fine:

```
function loadImages(){                                     
      var img_split = new Image();
      img_split.onload = function(){
      var this_canvas = img_canvas_split;
      this_canvas.width = w;
      this_canvas.height = h;
      this_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0,0, w, h);
      console.log("img 2");
  };
  img_split.src = path;

      var bg = new Image();
      bg.onload = function(){
      var this_canvas = bg_canvas;
      this_canvas.width = panorama_w;
      this_canvas.height = panorama_h;
      this_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, panoramaX,panoramaY, panorama_w, panorama_h);
      console.log("img 3");
   };
   bg.src = path_panorama;
}

var drawToMain = function(){
    ...
    main_ctx.drawImage( bg_b, 0, 0, bg_b.width * 0.5, bg_b.height * 0.5, panoramaX, panoramaY, bg_canvas.width, bg_canvas.height );
    main_ctx.translate(imageX+img_canvas.width/2, imageY+img_canvas.height/2);
    main_ctx.rotate(angle);
    main_ctx.translate(-(imageX+img_canvas.width/2),-(imageY+img_canvas.height/2));
    main_ctx.drawImage(img_canvas, imageX, imageY);
    main_ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
};
```

But when I call them like this:

```
loadImages().done( drawToMain );
```

It makes error as above.
Don't you have any idea how to solve this issue? I need to load my images first a then execute function.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23115928/2792083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use multi callback in your function. drawToMain function can be the call back of bg.onload; and bg.onload can be the callback of img_split.onload.

```
function loadImages(){                                     
  var img_split = new Image();
  var bg = new Image();

  img_split.onload = function(){
  var this_canvas = img_canvas_split;
  this_canvas.width = w;
  this_canvas.height = h;
  this_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0,0, w, h);
  console.log("img 2");

   img_split.src = path;

   // First callcack
   bg.onload = function(){
      var this_canvas = bg_canvas;
      this_canvas.width = panorama_w;
      this_canvas.height = panorama_h;
      this_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, panoramaX,panoramaY, panorama_w, panorama_h);
      console.log("img 3");
      bg.src = path_panorama;
      drawToMain(); // callback when all is done
   };
  };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.done()` function is used in context of xHR (ajax) callbacks. it will not work on a regular function without a deferred object. I don't see any specific asynchronous requests on this function. I would suggest a callback, as mentioned above, but you could also 'fake' a deferred using `$.when()`, ie. `$.when(loadImages()).done(drawToMain);` although this will execute immediately, so not sure what you would gain there.

The best solution would be to add the following to your `loadImages()` function:

```
function loadImages(callback){
  // rest of code
  // right before close tag: 
  if (!!callback && typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback();
  }
}
```

and then when you call the function: 
`loadImages(drawToMain());`

Note, this makes a lot of assumptions about how/where youre loading these scripts and how functions are organized. If you need to access variables in the first function, you could change `callback()` to `callback(this)` or `callback(bg)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to pass in a callback function:

```
function abc(callback) {
    //do some stuff...

    callback();
}

abc(function() { console.log('foo'); });
```

Comment: the problem is that callback() is executed in abc() so it will execute before images are loaded.

Comment: Oh, I see -- your question was a bit unclear. You could execute `callback()` inside the `onload()` handler for the image -- but if you're loading multiple images, it clearly becomes more complicated.