# cannot read property 'done' of undefined js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, asynchronous

I am quite new to js. I like to make an api call with jquery. I use [URL](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hyderabad&units=metric&APPID=44f90851c28b6bf322ad3ee2c4800e29) to get weather data from an openweatherapi.

I make my ajax call using following function:

```
myAjaxReq(){  
        var o = {url: "", datatype: "" };
        o.url = this.url;
        o.datatype = this.datatype;
        return $.ajax(o);
    }
```

Now when I try using following code, I get the results:

```
myAjaxReq().done(function(jsnData) {
    $("#c3").html(jsnData.name);
}).fail(function() {
  $("#c3").html("Something went wrong, please check the api request");
});
```

But I do something like below, I get the error saying "cannot read property 'done' of undefined"

```
var my_api_calls = {

        weather: function() {
                  myAjaxReq().then(function(jsndata) {
                  return jsndata.name;
                });
              }
};

my_api_calls.weather().done(function(weather) {
      $("#c3").append(weather);
});
```

I have looked into [link1](https://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises) to write the above code but doesnt work. I have also refered stacoverflow question about something similar [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115928/jquery-cannot-read-property-done-of-undefined-avoid-this), But could not understand.

Please guide me how it can be solved and what was the problem. Also I guess I am using jquery deffered objects, not promises. What is difference between them.

Comment: You forgot to write `function` before declaring `myAjaxReq()`.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the `weather()`-function

Comment: @jari -- I want to return jsndata.name. Can you please suggest me how its done

Comment: Just return `myAjaxReq().then(...)` from your `my_api_calls.weather` function

Comment: @jari thanks that helped ..

Answer (score 0):

Your function "weather" doesn't return anything. Take a look

```
 weather: function() {
              myAjaxReq().then(function(jsndata) {
                  return jsndata.name;
              });
          }
```

the return here is within promise. Which is something completely different. Maybe you want to return myAjaxReq() in function weather and chain callbacks?

Comment: I want to return jsndata.name so that I can use it in future to display it in a div. Can you please suggest me how its done

Comment: @sravankumar You have to assign to a global variable if you want to use it later.